# How to create the object if constructor for the class is internal

Tags: c#

I'm trying create an application that uses blockchain.info api. Found the [library](https://github.com/blockchain)

Now I'm trying to receive the price. We get the price via ExchangeRateExplorer.cs. :

```
public class ExchangeRateExplorer
{
    private IHttpClient httpClient { get; }

    internal ExchangeRateExplorer(IHttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<Dictionary<string, Currency>> GetTickerAsync()
    {
        //...
    }

    public async Task<double> ToBtcAsync(string currency, double value)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

As I understood, in order to use methods, I need to create an instance and use methods via the instance. But the constructor for the class is internal. How to use the methods of this class?
Probably a dumb question, but the question is not that simple for me.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: internal class can be called by the same assembly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/7c5ka91b.aspx -- normally the same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-csharp) is <strike>crappy and outdated</strike> not very explicit, but you need to create a [`BlockchainApiHelper(string apiCode = null, IHttpClient baseHttpClient = null, string serviceUrl = null, IHttpClient serviceHttpClient = null)`](https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-csharp/blob/master/src/Info.Blockchain.API/BlockchainApiHelper.cs).

Then you can access its properties, like `ExchangeRateExplorer`, on which you can call the method you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but if you're using an API class whose constructor is `internal`, that's because the author of the API did not intend for you to use that constructor as the client of the API.

I would look through the API documentation, if there is any, to get an idea of where and how you can obtain an instance of that class.  Look for a builder or a factory, for instance.

Comment: The documentation for the library is old. They rewrote the code, but didn't rewrite the documentation.